# Arguments in Plot function

Tags: matlab

The following Matlab scrip (taken from MATLAB help for fft) runs perfectly fine

```
Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz sinusoid and a 120 Hz sinusoid
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t); 
y = x + 2*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise
plot(Fs*t(1:50),y(1:50))
title('Signal Corrupted with Zero-Mean Random Noise')
xlabel('time (milliseconds)')
```

[image]

But I am unable to understand why we needed Fs*t in plot(). Why I am making it dimension less?

Comment: If this is strange, then what did you expect? (And what happens if you try to plot that)

Comment: It is consistent with the way you defined `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector t is defined in terms of samples, i.e. t(10) is the value taken as the 10th sample.

If you want to plot the signal vs. time, you will have to multiply the sampling instance with the sampling time, i.e. `time = FS*t` .

If you don't scale, you eventually plot the signal vs. the sampling instances. Then, however, the label "time(ms)" is not correct.